# Date Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have written a function using javascript for validating a Date selected from a calendar to a text box, with the current date. And I not getting a correct result. The date format displayed in text box is "01-Oct-2010". And the function i had created is as follows :

```
function CheckDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var startDate = document.getElementById("<%=txtStartDate.ClientID %>").value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById("<%=txtEndDate.ClientID %>").value;

    if (Date.parse(endDate) >= today) {
        alert("End Date should not be greater than Today");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDt=new Date(); 
myDOB = document.getElementById('dateField').value.split('-');
myDate = myDOB[0];
myMonth= getMonthInDigit(myDOB[1]);
myYear = myDOB[2];
var now = new Date();
myDt.setFullYear(myYear,myMonth,myDate); //here year, month, date value should be parsed from the value u get
var diff = (now.getTime() - myDt.getTime()) 
if(diff < 0){ 
  alert("End Date should not be greater than Today"); 
}
```

you can use the above javascript code.

Note: Make getMonthInDigit function which return value in digit as required.

Comment: Hi....This is working.....Thanks....I still dont know why the function which i had written is not working.

Comment: How does the above code work if you do not do more manipulation such as var myDt=new Date(Date.parse(endDate.replace(/-/g," "))); ???

Comment: @mplungjan- check the code now I have added how u can get values for month, year and date

Comment: @mplungjan - Its simply logical, depends upon how u define your function. One way can be to place if else ladder. :-)

Comment: I did not mean that as a real question. In your solution, you using a function that you did not define. I am questioning the verbosity of the solution and the missing function.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove dashes
2. test against today.getTime() since Date.parse returns a timestamp, not a date object

simply change

```
if (Date.parse(endDate) >= today) {
```

for

```
if (Date.parse(endDate.replace(/-/g," ")) >= today.getTime()) {
```

You may want to NORMALISE the date since the timestamp could be a few milliseconds greater than when the date was created:

```
var endTime = new Date(Date.parse(endDate.replace(/-/g," ")).setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime();
var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime();
if (endTime > today) {
```